# How to connect to remote Openfire server using StropheJS?

Tags: xmpp, openfire, strophe

I wonder how to use StropheJS to connect to a remote Openfire server?

Actually, I can connect to a local server using this:

```
$scope.connection = new Strophe.Connection('http://127.0.0.1:7070/http-bind/');
$scope.connection.connect($scope.jid, $scope.password, $scope.onConnect);
```

However, when I try connecting to a remote server, like this:

```
$scope.connection = new Strophe.Connection('http://172.21.2.217:7070/http-bind/');
$scope.connection.connect($scope.jid, $scope.password, $scope.onConnect);
```

the `$scope.onConnect` returns status of 1 (Strophe.Status.CONNECTING) and then status of 4 (Strophe.Status.AUTHFAIL).
The `$scope.jid` and `$scope.password` parameters work well when using Smack API to connect to remote Openfire server.

Thanks a lot!